# EXEC BAD ACCESS Error when calling a block (iPad only)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, block, exc-bad-access

In recent days I discovered that my Application crashes on iPads inconsistently. To try and found out why, I installed crashlytics and obtained a report on the crash after a user replicated it.

The error is an EXEC BAD ACCESS error on the main thread, and the line in question is: `__36-[CXScene showGenericPopupWithText:]_block_invoke`

Looking at my method 'showGenericPopupWithText:', I can see it does indeed invoke a block:

```
-(void)showGenericPopupWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    CXPopupMessageNode *message = [[CXPopupMessageNode alloc]initWithMessage:text];
    [message setAlpha:0.0f];
    [self.spriteForStaticGeometry addChild:message];
    [message setPosition:CGPointMake(self.spriteForStaticGeometry.size.width/2 - (message.frame.size.width/2), self.spriteForStaticGeometry.size.height/2)];
    SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.2];
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5];
    SKAction *fadeOut = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.2];
    SKAction *show = [SKAction sequence:@[fadeIn,wait,fadeOut]];
    [message runAction:show completion:^{
        [self.spriteForStaticGeometry removeChildrenInArray:@[message]];
    }];
}
```

Right at the end there, I run an action with a completion block that removes the `CXPopupMessageNode` object. (A subclass of `SKShapeNode`). I am assuming this is what is causing the error to occur.

However, this is only happening on certain iPads, and doesn't occur at all on any of the iPhones tested. What's more, I can't replicate this in the simulator, so I don't know exactly what I can do to fix this error. Might anyone know or have insight onto what is causing this crash?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit: Additional Information by Request:**

Crashlytics Stack Trace:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  SpriteKit                      0x26f9143a -[SKLabelNode hash] + 701
1  SpriteKit                      0x26f9140d -[SKLabelNode hash] + 656
2  CoreFoundation                 0x23b778d7 -[__NSSetI member:] + 62
3  CoreFoundation                 0x23b6610d -[NSSet containsObject:] + 28
4  CoreFoundation                 0x23b7a809 -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInRange:inArray:range:] + 304
5  CoreFoundation                 0x23b7a663 -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInArray:] + 154
6  SpriteKit                      0x26f7bb63 -[SKNode removeChildrenInArray:] + 1590
7  AstroKit                       0x00111873 __36-[CXScene showGenericPopupWithText:]_block_invoke (CXScene.m:707)
8  SpriteKit                      0x26f31847 SKCAction::didFinishWithTargetAtTime(SKCSprite*, double) + 38
9  SpriteKit                      0x26f46475 SKCSequence::cpp_updateWithTargetForTime(SKCSprite*, double) + 148
10 SpriteKit                      0x26f9c6a9 SKCSprite::update(double) + 144
11 SpriteKit                      0x26f9c767 SKCSprite::update(double) + 334
12 SpriteKit                      0x26f9c767 SKCSprite::update(double) + 334
13 SpriteKit                      0x26f4cec9 -[SKScene _update:] + 200
14 SpriteKit                      0x26f6a8af -[SKView(Private) _update:] + 686
15 SpriteKit                      0x26f67a45 -[SKView renderCallback:] + 748
16 SpriteKit                      0x26f6485d __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 116
17 SpriteKit                      0x26f95fcd -[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 248
18 QuartzCore                     0x26b3ad7b CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 98
19 QuartzCore                     0x26b3abe3 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 366
20 IOMobileFramebuffer            0x2b3c182f IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 90
21 IOKit                          0x24b6a51d IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 256
22 CoreFoundation                 0x23bfcbe5 __CFMachPortPerform + 132
23 CoreFoundation                 0x23c0d023 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
24 CoreFoundation                 0x23c0cfbf __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
25 CoreFoundation                 0x23c0b5e1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1608
26 CoreFoundation                 0x23b58db1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
27 CoreFoundation                 0x23b58bc3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
28 GraphicsServices               0x2aebb051 GSEventRunModal + 136
29 UIKit                          0x27124a31 UIApplicationMain + 1440
30 AstroKit                       0x0011ccdb main (main.m:14)
31 libdyld.dylib                  0x31c11aaf start + 2
```

Comment: try `NSZombieEnabled` ?

Comment: @Sreejith These crashes only happen on devices my testers have. Not on the simulator. Unless zombie objects work outside the Xcode environment, then I can't use them to help me.

Comment: Could you share the full stack trace as well as the implementation of `[CXPopupMessageNode runAction: completion:]`?

Comment: @hennes I have added the stack trace. I am not sure what you mean by the implementation of runAction: Completion:, it is a SpriteKit library method (Apple). Does not reveal much if I cmd-click on it, just the list of similar methods in the SKNode class.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that `CXPopupMessageNode` was your own code. The stack trace is, unfortunately, not very helpful. It smells like an ownership issue to me but I can't really see the source. The completion block lives on the stack and should capture a strong reference to `self` and `message` so you shouldn't have any dangling pointers. :/

Comment: @hennes Oh no, CXPopupMessageNode is my own code, but it is a subclass of SKNode. And runAction is an SKNode method. I believe that the pointer to message is the problem.